# C# Key Events - KeyDown

Tags: c#, keyevent

I have a Windows Form Application. I want some functions to work with the space key. But when I press the space key, the function I want is not working and it goes to the next form. (I did KeyPreview = true)

```
private void Form7_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
        {
            IEyeTracker eyeTracker = EyeTrackingOperations.FindAllEyeTrackers().FirstOrDefault();
            GazeDataStop(eyeTracker);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because:

1- If you have buttons, ... keydown won't work as form won't have focus anymore
2-you must handle the keydown so that it is not passed to ohter controls

Solution for 1:
set `KeyPreview` property of your form to true

Solution for 2:

set `e.Handled = true`:

```
private void Form7_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
        {
            IEyeTracker eyeTracker = EyeTrackingOperations.FindAllEyeTrackers().FirstOrDefault();
            GazeDataStop(eyeTracker);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @AkinGunduz You are welcome. Yardımcı ola bildiysem ne mutlu bana ;)